# Image click fadeout won't load the next image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to write a callback function that fadein the next image after fadeout the old one. But it seems like I can fadeout the image but I only fadein the old image instead of the new one. I think the first $("#image") will be the old one, but I don't know why it's still the old image after I reset its attr. The same thing happens in the caption too.

This is my .js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // set up event handlers for links    
    $("#image_list a").click(function(evt) {
        $("#image").fadeOut(1000,
        function(){
            var imageURL = $(this).attr("href");
            $("#image").attr("src", imageURL).fadeIn(1000);
        });
        $("#caption").fadeOut(1000,
        function(){
            var caption = $(this).attr("title");
            $("#caption").text(caption).fadeIn(1000);
        });

        //var imageURL = $(this).attr("href");
        //$("#image").attr("src", imageURL);
        //$("#image").fadeIn(1000);
        //var caption = $(this).attr("title");

        //$("#caption").text(caption);
        //$("#caption").fadeIn(1000);
        // cancel the default action of the link
        evt.preventDefault();
    }); // end click

    // move focus to first thumbnail
    $("li:first-child a").focus();
}); // end ready
```

This is my .html

```
<body>
    <main>
        <h1>Ram Tap Combined Test</h1>
        <ul id="image_list">
            <li><a href="images/h1.jpg" title="James Allison: 1-1">
                <img src="thumbnails/t1.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
            <li><a href="images/h2.jpg" title="James Allison: 1-2">
                <img src="thumbnails/t2.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
            <li><a href="images/h3.jpg" title="James Allison: 1-3">
                <img src="thumbnails/t3.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
            <li><a href="images/h4.jpg" title="James Allison: 1-4">
                <img src="thumbnails/t4.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
            <li><a href="images/h5.jpg" title="James Allison: 1-5">
                <img src="thumbnails/t5.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
            <li><a href="images/h6.jpg" title="James Allison: 1-6">
                <img src="thumbnails/t6.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
        </ul>
        <h2 id="caption">James Allison: 1-1</h2>               
        <p><img src="images/h1.jpg" alt="" id="image"></p>
    </main> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a problem with `this`, note `that` as replacement of `this`

```
$("#image_list a").click(function(evt) {
    // Here this is element of #image_list a
    var that = this;
    $("#image").fadeOut(1000, function(){
        // Here this is element of #image
        var imageURL = $(that).attr("href");
        $("#image").attr("src", imageURL).fadeIn(1000);
    });
    $("#caption").fadeOut(1000, function(){
        // Here this is element of #image
        var caption = $(that).attr("title");
        $("#caption").text(caption).fadeIn(1000);
    });

    //var imageURL = $(this).attr("href");
    //$("#image").attr("src", imageURL);
    //$("#image").fadeIn(1000);
    //var caption = $(this).attr("title");

    //$("#caption").text(caption);
    //$("#caption").fadeIn(1000);
    // cancel the default action of the link
    evt.preventDefault();
}); // end click
```

Comment: Glad it could help.